# What does the "No owner type for enclosed interface" guice error mean?

Tags: java, types, guice, inner-classes, nested-class

I'm trying to generate a `ParameterizedType` using Guice's `Types` library.  `Butler` is an inner class or inner interface.  When I use the code like the [following](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-guice@googlegroups.com/msg03911.html), I get the error "No owner type for enclosed interface".  Why?

```
private Butler<Person> findButler(Person person, Injector injector){
   Class<? extends Person> personClass = person.getClass();

   ParameterizedType parameterizedButler =
   Types.newParameterizedType(Butler.class, personClass);

   Key<?> key = Key.get(parameterizedButler);
   Butler<Person> butler = (Butler<Person>) injector.getInstance(key);
   return butler
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Sam Berlin's [answer](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-guice@googlegroups.com/msg03911.html), the "No owner type for enclosed interface" error means that if [in this case] Butler is an inner class, you'll need to use the [three-argument
newParameterizedTypeWithOwner method](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Types.html#newParameterizedTypeWithOwner-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.reflect.Type...-) and pass the outer class as the owner [first] argument.

So the correct code would look something like this:

```
private Butler<Person> findButler(Person person, Injector injector){
   Class<? extends Person> personClass = person.getClass();

   ParameterizedType parameterizedButler =
   Types.newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(ButlersOuter.class, Butler.class, personClass);

   Key<?> key = Key.get(parameterizedButler);
   Butler<Person> butler = (Butler<Person>) injector.getInstance(key);
   return butler
}
```